# Two line text in modal header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a default modal. I wanna two line text in header as a 
`Payment Information` 
`Description smth`
 I tried smth you can see below but it doesn't work correctly. I mean it works but it has a too much top and bottom space
any helps? Thanks in advance!

```
    <!--begin::Modal dialog-->
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered mw-650px">
        <!--begin::Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <!--begin::Modal header-->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <!--begin::Modal title-->
            <div>
              <h2>Payment</h2>
              <!--begin::Notice-->
              <p class="text-gray-400 fs-6">store credit</p>
              <!--end::Notice-->
            </div>
            <!--end::Modal title-->
    
            <!--begin::Close-->
            <div
              class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-active-color-primary"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            >
              <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-1">
                <inline-svg src="media/icons/duotune/arrows/arr061.svg" />
              </span>
            </div>
            <!--end::Close-->
          </div>
          <!--end::Modal header-->
          </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: either your close button has many padding and margin or you set margin-top for that gray line

Comment: @cfarhad i didn't write css for any part except for what you see. Only `default` modal

Comment: please take a screenshot of your inspected elements.  i need to see your elements width or hight or padding or margin

Comment: @cfarhad thx for helps. The solution in the answer seems to be working now. you can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `<p>` and `<h2>` inherently have margins above and below the elements. If you want to remove them, you can set their css or style to `margin:0`

Answer (score 0):

you can use css style

```
.modal-header {
  line-height: 0;
}
```